# Perceptron find weight exercise

Tags: machine-learning

I have some difficulties with the following exercise.

> There are three different diagrams. If possible, ﬁnd the perceptron-weights $w_0, w_1,$ and $w_2$ for each of them (the decision surface is clearly divided into two regions, one ”positive” the other one ”negative”).

[image]

Solution: for diagram 1 it's obvious that the function is $x_2=x_1$, does it mean that $w_0=0,w_1=-1,w_2=1$?

for diagram 2, the function is $0.7x_1+x_2+1.4=0$, does it mean that $w_0=1.4, w_1=0.7, w_2=1$? If the direction makes any sense here?

for diagram 3, $x_2=|x_1|$, I am not sure how to define weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions for 1 and 2 are correct, since the [perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)'s weight vector is perpendicular to the [decision boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_boundary).

For diagram 3, there is no solution because the perceptron is a [linear classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier) (i.e. the decision boundary is [always](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_separable) a single line).

Answer (score 0):

Classifier for 1 is correct. **Classifier for 2 is incorrect**:

Test with your classifier ($w_0=+1.4, w_1=+0.7, w_2=+1$) and $x_1=-3, x_2=0$:
$$
y=f_step(w0+w1*x1+w2*x2)=f_step(+1.4+(-3*+0.7)+(0*1)=f_step(+1.4-
2.1)=f_step(-0.7)=-1 
$$
 **--> incorrect classification as (-), should be (+)**

Classifier 2 **should** be: $w_0=-1.4, w_1=-0.7, w_2=-1$.

Test for classifier 2 with x1=-3, x2=0:
$$
y=f_step(w_0+w_1*x_1+w_2*x_2)=f_step(-1.4+(-3*-0.7)+(0*-1)=f_step(-1.4+2.1)=f_step(+0.7)=1 
$$
**--> correct classifcation as (+)**

As already mentioned in the above answer, the 3rd example cannot be separated by a single perceptron.