# Perceptron Exercise Finding Slope-Intercept Form of Boundary Line

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

Given the following information:

I have a function $$h(x)=\mathbf{sign}(w^Tx)$$

I also have the following weights: $$w=[w_0,w_1,w_2]^T$$

I also have the following coordinates: $$x=[1,x_1,x_2]^T$$

The problem statement is find the equation of the line given when $h(x)=\pm 1$ in the following format $x_2=ax_1+b$

This is how I have been setting up the problem as such:
\begin{align}
\pm1&=w_0+x_1w_1+x_2w_2\\
\frac{-x_1w_1-w_0\mp1}{w_2}&=x_2\\
x_2 &= \frac{-x_1w_1}{w_2}-\frac{w_0\mp1}{w_2}
\end{align}

Is the approach to the problem near the to how I would get the solution?

Linked Questions:
[Perceptron find weight exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660814/perceptron-find-weight-exercise)